# Nginx Autoindex with XSLT

Tags: nginx, xslt, ubuntu-18.04

I try autoindex with XSLT stylesheet on NGINX.

now i can't print out the folder name on the main body ?
i try a few things but all not work it still view directory on all folders.
here is my last try.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>

            <h3><xsl:value-of select="name(//directory)"/></h3>

            <table border="0">
                <tr bgcolor="#7DAFFF">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="list/*">
                    <xsl:sort select="mtime" />

                    <xsl:variable name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:variable name="size">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length(@size) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:if test="number(@size) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="round(@size div 1024) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="@size" /></xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="round(@size div 1048576) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="format-number((@size div 1024), '0.0')" />K</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number((@size div 1048576), '0.00')" /> MB</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:variable name="date">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,9,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,6,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,1,4)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,12,2)"/>:<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,15,2)"/>:<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,18,2)"/>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{$name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></td>
                        <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="$size"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$date"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `                    <xsl:sort select="mtime" />` at least should have "@mtime", not "mtime"

Comment: "@mtime" works thx 